# How to capture screen touch event when screen is off in Android?

Tags: android

I write a program to capture screen touch event. But when the screen is off, I can't get any `MotionEvent ev`.

```
private PowerManager pm = null;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl = null;
this.pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
this.wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "test");
wl.acquire();

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        Log.i("test", "!!!");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This should answer the question for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572750/touch-event-while-display-off

Answer (score -1):

you can use Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF to achieve your goal. [this link](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) might help you.