# Touch event while display off

Tags: android, touch, display-manager

Sorry for stupid question, but can I listening touch events from android phone, while display is off? Or touch system works only when display is ON..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only when the display is **on** since the touchscreen needs power to detect touches.
However, there is some [research](http://nosemaj.org/android-persistent-sensors) to re-register the sensors when the screen is off, so maybe you'll have some luck if you follow that route.

**Useful Resources:**

- [Getting Android Sensor Events While The Screen is Off](http://nosemaj.org/android-persistent-sensors)
- [Android docs - Partial wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)
- [Example app on gitHub](https://github.com/jamesonwilliams/AndroidPersistentSensors)

Comment: The nosemaj.org link does not work anymore...I'm guessing the website went offline in 2017, according to web.archive.org (Wayback Machine). But you can still access the links through the Wayback Machine.

Comment: What about more recently changes? Various devices can detect double tap to wake the device. Wouod there be some way to mimic on unsupported devices? (as a system app and/or root user rights)

Comment: This is an answer from 8 years ago, you can't expect an answer from 8 years ago to be kept up to date. If anyone has more information, feel free to edit it or answer again. I made it a community wiki so I no longer _own_ this