# Wake screen on single screen tap, when the screen is turned off

Tags: android, screen, turn

I had used the code below to lock the device, and turn the device screen light off.

I need to unlock the device and turn the screen light ON by a single tap on the device screen.

```
val policyManager =context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
val adminReceiver = ComponentName(context, KioskAdmin::class.java!!)
val admin = policyManager.isAdminActive(adminReceiver)
if (admin) {
    Log.i("TURN_OFF", "Going to sleep now.")
    policyManager.lockNow()
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572750/touch-event-while-display-off  this might help you

Comment: you can't detect taps on the screen when it is off.

Comment: @ZaidMirza I checked and tested the link you shared but It didn't worked.... The Sensor are calling everytime the screen is off and even the screen is tapped or not by the user

Comment: @ZaidMirza I need to get the touch event when the screen is off and tapped by user