# I want to click on lockscreen to count

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am new in android and also new on stackoverflow. 
I am making an app in which i need a count button on lock screen. actully when i touch the screen it counts increase and after unlock phone it show the total count. how it possible ?

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // 타이틀화면도 없이 전체화면으로 실행
    getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);
```

Comment: Please include some code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319531/2506522

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572750/touch-event-while-display-off